# Как задать иконку приложения

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо значка android была моя иконка?

В манифесте уже прописал android:icon и android:roundIcon. Иконку на рабочем столе видно, но в таком положении - нет.

Скачал приложение на другом устройстве. Все хорошо отображается. Проблема не с кодом. Какие-нибудь решения?
[image: скриншот]

Comment: Код Манифеста покажите ваш, котёнок)

Answer (score 4):

В файле `AndroidManifest.xml` вместо стандартной иконки `ic_launcher` укажите вашу новую иконку.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня уже прописаны android:icon и android:roundIcon.

Comment: @Дмитрий К сожалению, с таким не сталкивался еще (

Comment: Скачал приложение на другом устройстве. Все хорошо отображается. Проблема не с кодом. Какие-нибудь решения?

Comment: @Дмитрий может переустановите приложение на этом устройстве ?

Comment: Переустанавил. Проблема не решилась + появилась новая. Скачивая уже из Google Play, у меня открывается не та версия приложения. Причём опять же: на других телефонах все работает корректно

Comment: @Дмитрий очень странно

Answer (score 2):

Если вы планируете использовать приложение на большом количестве устройств, вы должны поместить значок своего приложения в различные `res/drawable...`папки. В каждой из этих папок вы должны указать значок размера `48dp`:

```
drawable-ldpi (120 точек на дюйм, экран с низкой плотностью) - 36 пикселей x 36 пикселей

drawable-mdpi (160 точек на дюйм, экран средней плотности) - 48 пикселей x 48 пикселей

drawable-hdpi (240 dpi, экран высокой плотности) - 72px x 72px

drawable-xhdpi (320 точек на дюйм, Экстра высокой плотности) - 96 пикселей x 96 пикселей

drawable-xxhdpi (480 точек на дюйм, Экстра сверхвысокой плотности) - 144px x 144px

drawable-xxxhdpi (640 точек на дюйм, Экстра сверхвысокочастотный экран) - 192px x 192px
```

Затем вы можете определить значок в своем AndroidManifest.xmlфайле как таковой:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon_name" android:label="@string/app_name" >
.... 
</application>
```

Comment: иконка приложения по стандарту находится в папках mipmap

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня уже прописаны android:icon и android:roundIcon. Причем назначал я изображения из minmap. То есть размерность у меня соблюдена. Иконка на рабочем столе отображается, но здесь нет

Comment: Это абсолютно неверный ответ, вы не сможете разместить ваше приложение в googleplay если сделаете так, необходимо использовать mipmap и пока только растр.